# .NET framework уже установлен, но его нет и не работают программы на .net

Tags: .net

[image: powershell не работает][image: DotNetVersions видит установленный .NET 4.0][image: Установщик .NET 4.0 говорит что уже установлена эта версия][image: Установщик .NET 4.8 говорит что тоже установлен]

Все началось с того, что 1 программа использовала устаревший компонент .NET и я поставил для нее .NET framework 4.6.1, но это не помогло. Я поставил новее версии, сначала 4.8, потом 5.0, потом решил удалить все что связано с .NET и поставить заново старую версию, но установщики говорили что .NET уже стоит, хотя я все удалил. Тогда я пробовал .NET Framework Setup Cleanup Utility, CCleaner и .NET Framework Repair Tool, но это тоже не дало никакого эффекта, .NET не работал и установить я его не мог. Тогда я начал чистить реестр, уничтожил половину реестра, уже перестали работать даже powershell, а установщик все еще где-то видит .NET. Я пытался вернуть хотя бы .NET 4.0, чтобы powershell заработал, но он так и не заработал. .NET Framework Setup Verification Tool сообщил что .NET 4.0 не установлен до конца и не работает. Я не знаю что уже делать, как поставить .NET framework 4.6.1? Есть ли еще способы без переустановки Windows 10 20H2 x64?

Answer (score 1):

Ну если вы уже руками чистили реестр, сложно будет что то восстановить, если задели то что не нужно. А произошло ли это уже вряд ли узнаете. Попробуйте откатить Винду до одной из точек восстановления, может поможет. Желательно на состояние до того момента когда начались проблемы

Comment: Хорошо, я восстановился, удалил 4.8 и 5.0 версии через удаление программ и пытаюсь установить 4.6.1. Установщик говорит ".NET Framework 4.6.1 или более позднее обновление уже установлены на этом компьютере.". Что делать? DotNetVersions все еще видит 4.8

Comment: А после восстановления пробовали не удалять существующие фреймворки?

Comment: Но мне же нужна версия 4.6.1. Программа использует System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu. Или вы знаете как на новом фреймворке заставить работать этот компонент?

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas этот компонент есть во всех версиях фрэймворка. Более того, фрэймворк версии 4.х должен позволять запускать программы написанные на версии от 4.0 до 4.х. По крайней мере так гласит официальная документация от майкрософт. А вот ссылка на документацию по вашему контролу https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenu?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: А почему тогда программа не работала? Ошибка была при подгрузке этого компонента.